# HTTPClient POST works on postman but not inside a c# application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, rest, cross-domain

I am trying to use a Rest API from outside my company's domain. My problem is when I run the POST request within Postman or an Angular application it works fine. But when I send the same payload within a winforms c# application, I get **Access Forbidden. You have browsed from an unrecognized IP address.** The proxy therefore denied access to this site.

I thought the problem was with the payload itself, so I copied the same JSON string, sent it via postman and It worked. So I thought perhaps the issue is with the server itself, so I ran other GET requests to the same server and they worked. I tried sending an empty string to the POST request and it worked, tried an empty object and get **FORBIDDEN REQUEST**. The same code, I ran it from my personal computer and it worked.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", sToken);
StringContent sRequestContent = new StringContent(requestPayload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");sRequestContent).Result;
var result = client.PostAsync(new Uri(sUrl), sRequestContent).Result;
return result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

**PS:**
requestPayload is a JSON string.

Comment: The error message says it all: "You have browsed from an unrecognized IP address. The proxy therefore denied access to this site"

Comment: Postman works on the same PC as your WinForms app?

Comment: @Jon Yes.Eric very request I do to the same server from the same application works. Except for POST.

Comment: I changed the c# HTTPClient to RestSharp and it works now. I am not quite sure what the issue is but it seems that the httpclient is causing the issue.